# Правильный механизм формирования тегов (меток) на сайте

Tags: алгоритм, интерфейс

Сейчас в интернет-проектах используются следующие механизмы формирования тегов:

1. **Белый список тегов** (юзер может устанавливать из списка зараннее заготовленных администрацией тегов) - как на ХэшКоде. Преимущество данного способа: чистота тегов (нет мусора). Недостаток: упускается много дополнительных тегов, список не расширяется коллективным разумом.
2. **Определяются на усмотрение юзера**.  Преимущество: разнообразность, саморасширяемость. Недостатки: много мусора (юзеры ставят какие-попало теги, либо вообще пишут в теги "я, не умею, пользоваться, тегами"), дублирующиеся по смыслу теги (к примеру - по тегам "WoW" и "WarCraft" найдутся разные посты, хотя тег по смыслу один).
3. **Ручная модерация тегов к каждому посту**. Преимущества: решаются недостатки 1 и 2 пункта. Недостаток - требуется работа модератора, если в день более 1000 новых публикаций, модератору вручную будет невозможно все проверить.

Из-за этих всех недостатков теги теряют свою полезность. Хотелось бы придумать способ, позволяющий избавиться от недостатков выше, или хотя бы приблизиться к идеалу (минимум вмешательства модератора, нет мусора, саморасширяемость, нет дублирующихся тегов).

Выскажите плз ваши соображения по поводу правильного формирования списка тегов?

Comment: @kanaris, это вопрос на форум мета.



А по существу, добавить бы возможность модераторам объединять теги. Ну и поиск по нескольким сразу - и было бы идеально

Comment: Причем здесь хешкод? Вопрос вообще не про ваш сайт. Хэшкод был приведен лишь как пример сайта, где теги премодерируемые.
Мой вопрос относится к программированию, к построению алгоритмов и интерфейсов (интересуюсь, т.к. хочу накодить сабжевую систему). Метки я правильно расставил.

Comment: >Хэшкод был приведен лишь как пример



@kanaris, прошу прощения, это я не уловил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 и 3 совместить.

- вести список клонов меток (ваш WoW и WarCraft, хотя люди еще помнят и без "world'а of.."), автоматически менять на них.
- новые метки подсвечивать для модераторов, которые либо удаляют либо добавляют новые метки одним кликом.

еще есть вариант забить на метки, слишком тонкий инструмент, мало кто ими умеет пользоваться.

ЗЫ [нытье on]на ХК метки, например, неудобны. поиск по ним возможен только по одной за раз, а для идентификации "о чем вопрос вообще" хватает либо одной метки, либо метки как попало. например, на ХК 98% вопросов по запросам и mysql в частности содержат метку php. типа если текст запроса скопировать из кода вместе mysql_fetch и прочим мусором от этого что-то изменится или кому-то удобнее будет...[нытье off]